# How to fix "error C1083: Cannot open include file :'simpleclass.h' :no such file or directory" when using a library?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, shared-libraries

I have a very very simple C++ class and tool is QT Creator.
I created a **Non-QT project**.
Have the SimpleClass class as given below

### **simpleclass.h**

```
#ifndef SIMPLECLASS_H
#define SIMPLECLASS_H

class SimpleClass
{
public:
    SimpleClass();
    void printLine();
};

#endif // SIMPLECLASS_H
```

### **simpleclass.cpp**

```
#include "simpleclass.h"
#include <iostream>

SimpleClass::SimpleClass()
{
    printf("Hello , This is SimpleClass constructor\n");
}

void SimpleClass::printLine()
{
    printf(" Printing a Line\n");
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "simpleclass.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    SimpleClass sc;
    sc.printLine();
    return 0;
}
```

All good till here!

The problem and confusion  starts now!
Now my aim is to create a simple library testlibrary.lib and .dll and use it in another project.

I create a C++ library project called TestLibrary and try to build a library containing that one simple class(SimpleClass).

The files look as given below

### TestLibrary.pro

```
QT       += widgets

TARGET = TestLibrary
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += TESTLIBRARY_LIBRARY

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS


SOURCES += \
    simpleclass.cpp

HEADERS += \
        testlibrary_global.h \ 
    simpleclass.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

**testlibrary_global.h**

```
#ifndef TESTLIBRARY_GLOBAL_H
#define TESTLIBRARY_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(TESTLIBRARY_LIBRARY)
#  define TESTLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define TESTLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // TESTLIBRARY_GLOBAL_H
```

### simpleclass.h

```
#ifndef TESTLIBRARY_H
#define TESTLIBRARY_H

#include "testlibrary_global.h"

class TESTLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT SimpleClass
{

public:
    SimpleClass();
    void printLine();
};

#endif // TESTLIBRARY_H
```

similarly, I have the simpleclass.cpp .

On building, The libraries TestLibrary.lib and TestLibrary.dll do get created but I am not able to use it in another project named UseLibrary.
I created a directory libs under a new project UseLibrary and copied TestLibrary.lib and TestLibrary.dll there.

[image: Project directory structure showing folder where I copied the lib and dll]

### UseLibrary.pro file looks as given below

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
    main.cpp

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ -lTestLibrary

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libs
```

### main.cpp(in the project UseLibrary)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "simpleclass.h" ---> error C1083: Cannot open include file :'simpleclass.h' :no such file or directory. 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    SimpleClass sc; --> Unknown Type name 'Simpleclass', # include header itself giving error so obvious issue
    sc.printLine();
    return 0;
}
```

**`#include "simpleclass.h" ---> error C1083: Cannot open include file :'simpleclass.h' :no such file or directory.`**
*Why am I getting this error??* I read many library creation related posts and I am perplexed as to why  most of the posts have

`#include <QWidget>` or `#include <QtGlobal>`. *Why do we need these??*

At least I never used these framework classes in my code! Are these really required in library creation? Why?
From what I understand, my project is a Non-QT project, so I do not need these. Can anyone point out if my understanding is correct?
What am I missing? and Finally, why is the simpleclass.h header file not getting included??

Comment: are the include files in `$$PWD/libs`?

Comment: The lib and DLL are there.. In fact QT itself added these lines, I simply browsed to the libs folder using the file browser

Comment: Do you compile your code as a debug, or a release build?

Comment: I compiled as debug

Comment: compile it as a release and see what happens.

Comment: Compiled as release, same issue..

Comment: You didn't answer the question of @AlanBirtles. Besides, put `@` and my name after that if you reply to me, otherwise I am not getting notified.

Comment: @AlanBirtles -  the lib and DLL files are there.. $$PWD/libs was added by QT creator itself, I simply browsed to the directory. I have added screenshot of the project directory for clarity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223214/discussion-between-scopchanov-and-rohit-ganeshan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause

Your include path is set to `$$PWD/libs`:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs
```

but the screenshot does not show `simpleclass.h` in that location.

### Solution

1. Delete from `UseLibrary.pro`:

   ```
    win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ -lTestLibrary

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libs
   ```
2. Right click the `UseLibrary` project in the project browser in QtCreator and select `Add library`
3. Select `External library`
4. **Important**: First click on browse on the "Include path" row and select the path, where the `simpleclass.h` is
5. Now, click browse on the "Library file" row and select the path, where the `TestLibrary.lib` is

**Note:** If you first select a library file path, QtCreator misleadingly fills out the include path box with the same path. Following the above steps should help you overcome this issue.

Comment: I performed the steps and now I am getting a different error message ```C1083: Cannot open include file:'QtCore/qglobal.h': No such file or directory```.. do I need to add framework class headers also in the include path?

Comment: @RohitGaneshan, remove `CONFIG -= qt` from `UseLibrary.pro`.

Comment: @RohitGaneshan and add `QT += widgets`.

Comment: I did the as suggested but same issue persists.. Also  you might notice above  ```testlibrary_global.h``` has ```#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>``` include declaration.

Comment: Tried to add @scopchanov multiple times in the above comment.. it gets auto-removed as soon I add the comment :I

Comment: @RohitGaneshan, when you comment under my post, there is no need to do that.

Comment: Issue resolved. I did a clean and rebuild now it works.

Comment: @RohitGaneshan, I am glad this have solved your issue!

Comment: What do QT+= widgets or CONFIG -= qt mean here in terms of dependency? Knowing these minutes will be helpful

Comment: I have never used any QT GUI in my program, so why do I need to add widgets is something I am not able to understand..also, will such a library built using QT creator be given to another developer who is using ,say, Visual Studio as the development tool?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223248/discussion-between-scopchanov-and-rohit-ganeshan).